# NDK: Pass text field value to c++ string

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Im into android but not the apps itself. Im trying to re-create my school work as an Android app with NDK -> [MyczkowskiAdam/LuckyNumbersCppCMD](https://github.com/MyczkowskiAdam/LuckyNumbersCppCMD/blob/visual-studio/LuckyNumbers.cpp)
Printing output from C++ to text field is not a problem but in order for my program to work I have to pass two strings (FirstName & LastName) with input from textfield to C++ and store them so that main program can interpret it and thats what Im really struggling with.

In my C++ file I have the main program process to which I have to pass FrNm and LstNm:

```
int LuckyNumbersProcess(std::string FrNm, std::string LstNm) {
    //stuff
    //return LuckyNumber (int)
}
```

Then I have the native function that runs LuckyNumbersProcess and writes LuckyNumber to a textfield:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_android_mycax_luckynumbers_MainActivity_Calculate (JNIEnv *env, 
jobject ) {
    LuckyNumbersProcess(FrNmFromJava, LstNmFromJava);
    std::string sLuckyNumber = NumberToString(LuckyNumber);
    return env->NewStringUTF(sLuckyNumber.c_str());
}
```

Input from text fields show be stored in FrNmFromJava and LstNmFromJava but how do I go about this?

I have tried this method:

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL 
Java_com_android_mycax_luckynumbers_MainActivity_GetFirstName (JNIEnv * env, 
jobject jobj) {

    const char *str;

    jclass myclass_class =(jclass) env->NewGlobalRef
            (env->FindClass ("GetFirstNameFromField"));

    // we need the MyClass constructor
    jmethodID constructorID = env->GetMethodID
            (myclass_class, "", "()V");

    // and the sayHello() method
    jmethodID methodID = env->GetMethodID
            (myclass_class, "iFirstName", "()Ljava/lang/String;");

    // instanciate a MyClass object
    jobject myclass_object =  env->NewObject
            (myclass_class, constructorID);

    // call the sayHello() method
    jstring s = (jstring)  env->CallObjectMethod
            (myclass_object, methodID);

    // convert the Java String to use it in C
    str = env->GetStringUTFChars(s, 0);
    //printf("%s" , str);
    FrNmFromJava = str;
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(s, str);

}
```

But it returns that JNI NewGlobalRef called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "GetFirstNameFromField" on path:

This is my Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


// Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
static {
    System.loadLibrary("luckynumbers");
}

EditText mFirstName;
EditText mLastName;
Button mButton;
GetFirstNameFromField gfn = new GetFirstNameFromField();
GetLastNameFromField gln = new GetLastNameFromField();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
    mLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastName);
    mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    mButton.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    gfn.iFirstName();
                    gln.iLastName();
                    GetFirstName();
                    GetLastName();
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
                    tv.setText(Calculate());
                }
            });
}

public class GetFirstNameFromField {
    public String iFirstName() {
        return mFirstName.getText().toString();
    }
}
public class GetLastNameFromField {
    public String iLastName() {
        return mLastName.getText().toString();
    }
}
/**
 * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
 * which is packaged with this application.
 */
public native String Calculate();

public native String GetFirstName();

public native String GetLastName();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: The argument to `FindClass` should be a _fully-qualified_ class name. For example, `java/lang/String` is a fully-qualified class name, while `String` is not. Also, depending on where you're calling your JNI functions from, this might be relevant: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_FindClass

Comment: The whole things looks strangely designed, though. Why can't you just call `getText().toString()` on your two `EditText`s and pass those strings to `Calculate`?

Comment: I tried the second thing before but it didnt seem to work, probably because   I was calling the method wrongly. Anyway if pass one string (from first textbox ) directly onto calculate it works and Im able to copy its value and run LuckyNumbersProcess, write number is calculated but how can I receive both of the strings in jni? I can pass them but I need to receive them as separate variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I got it, everything is working now.

In java I just passed two string to the native method

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mFirstName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstName);
        mLastName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastName);
        mButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(View view)
                    {
                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
                    tv.setText(Calculate(mFirstName.getText().toString(),mLastName.getText().toString()));
                }
            });
    }

    public native String Calculate(String jFirstName, String jLastName);
```

And in c++

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL 
Java_com_android_mycax_luckynumbers_MainActivity_Calculate (JNIEnv *env, jobject, jstring cFirstName, jstring cLastName) {
    const char *path = env->GetStringUTFChars(cFirstName, NULL);
    const char *path2 = env->GetStringUTFChars(cLastName, NULL);
    FrNmFromJava = ToString(path);
    LstNmFromJava = ToString(path2);
    LuckyNumbersProcess(FrNmFromJava, LstNmFromJava);
    std::string sLuckyNumber = ToString(LuckyNumber);
    ClearAll();
    return env->NewStringUTF(sLuckyNumber.c_str());
}
```